# Is it a good idea to use ionic to build mobile web version of a website?

Tags: angularjs, html, mobile, web, ionic-framework

I work for a Startup, we decide to have an adaptive website rather than a responsive one, so we basically serve different views for different devices, so that we provide the best experience for both ends [mobile,desktop], we are about to rebuild our mobile website, and since i have this privilege i'm trying to figure out what is the best Framework to use, one good choice is 
http://mobileangularui.com/, the other choice is http://ionicframework.com/, i know ionic is used more to build html5 mobile apps, so i was wondering if it will make sense to use it for the web version as well, what do you think?

Answer (score 5):

I am working on a similiar project that needs a mobile webiste and native apps are a nice to have. I have chosen the Ionic framework. Let me explain the reasons:

What it takes to build a mobile website is a style framework, such as Bootstrap or Google's Web Starter Kit. The latter has drawbacks, because styling of some important elements like forms is still missing.

Bootstrap is also a convenient way to go. Though we've seen so many of such sites, eyes getting tired.

I personally have chosen Ionic since it has a truly mobile first experience, meaning do not use it for your desktop. But sites in mobile browser will look more like apps than just a mobile version of your desktopt site.

If mobile conversion is of importance to you, such as in ecommerce, I'd definetely recommend using Ionic. It has a fresh look and is damn fast. As said a nice feature on top is having at minimum costs a native app.

By the way: I do not see a must in using Cordova. Though you could still cherry pick some of their features for your native app and leave mobile site plain vanilla.

Comment: I totally agree with you and think the same, it's making the development process really fast and the results are awesome too.
And like you said, after all it's just Css & JavaScript! same as using bootstrap or any other framework!

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on an `ionic` app and following are my thoughts, I personally think its not a good idea to use `ionicframework` for your web app.

1) AFAIK ionic doesnt have a web server, and its testing server uses UIWebview and will not allow for POST requests.

2 )`ionic` is more optimized for app development. What I mean by that is , there is this really cool repository called [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/) which will allows you to use native plugins like `camera`, which you cannnot use in the web app

So having said that, for hybrid mobile application development I highly recommand it :)

HTH

Comment: which version of ionic where you using? 1 or 2?